# Making a large json file quickly available in python

Tags: python, json, storage, pickle

I have a multiple-json file of about 5 GB on which I do some exploratory data analysis. The problem is that each time I load the file it takes about 1 minute to load it when using this code:

```
with open(json_fn, 'r') as f:   # multiple jsons in one file! (one per line)
   for line in f:
       data = json.loads(line)
```

Is there a more efficient way to store these data for loading it in python? I was thinking about pickle (as it is a binary format which is usually faster)  but [it seems to be even slower](https://konstantin.blog/2010/pickle-vs-json-which-is-faster/). Any recommendations what I could use to avoid waiting 1 minute every time?

Comment: The purpose of `pickle` is to save and restore arbitrary Python objects, not to efficiently store text data.

Comment: If the rows have identical (or largely identical) structure, is it an option to store them in a proper database? If you can pickle, surely you can push to MySQL, sqlite, or whatever.

Comment: Maybe even csv would make sense (simpler to parse) if your data does not need quoting and you're stuck with plain files :-D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ijson` for this purpose. ijson allows reading the file lazily as a stream.

```
import ijson

json_data = ijson.parse(open(FILE_PATH, 'r'))

for prefix, event, value in json_data:
    print(value)
```

Refer [this](https://pypi.org/project/ijson/).

NOTE: With the help of backends mentioned in this [post](https://lpetr.org/2016/05/30/faster-json-parsing-python-ijson/) you can increase the performance quiet a lot.

Comment: This is pretty much what the OP is already doing; it just combines the file read and the one-line parse in the same iterator.

Comment: @chepner No he uses the inbuilt json library. I suggested ijson

Comment: Yes, and that iterator does the same thing as the OP"s code: it reads a single line from the file and parses it as JSON.

Comment: But is it faster than reading and json.loading one line at a time? I see nothing in the docs about a speedup

Comment: I think the main benefit of `ijson` is to parse a *single* value  lazily, not a series of values in a single file.

Comment: Instead of loading the whole file into memory and parsing everything at once, it uses iterators to lazily load the data.

Comment: Yes, but for the EDA I do not know which parts I need i.e. iterative does not really help - reading everything with ijson is about 5 sec slower ...